# Processing data in directories with specific date range using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to load Incremental Data from HDFS folder using Spark Scala code.
So suppose if I have the following folders:

```
/hadoop/user/src/2021-01-22
/hadoop/user/src/2021-01-23
/hadoop/user/src/2021-01-24
/hadoop/user/src/2021-01-25
/hadoop/user/src/2021-01-26
/hadoop/user/src/2021-01-27
/hadoop/user/src/2021-01-28
/hadoop/user/src/2021-01-29
```

I am giving path `/hadoop/user/src` from spark-submit command then writing below code

```
val Temp_path: String = args(1) // hadoop/user/src
val incre_path = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")).minusDays(1)
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
val incre_path_day = formatter format incre_path
val new_path = Temp_path.concat("/")
val path = new_path.concat(incre_path_day)
```

So it processes (sysdate-1) folder i.e. today's date is `2021-01-29` so it will process `2021-01-28` directory's data.

Is there any way to modify code so I can give  path like `hadoop/user/src/2021-01-22` and code will process data till `2021-01-28` (i.e. 2021-01-23, 2021-01-24, 2021-01-25, 2021-01-26, 2021-01-27, 2021-01-28).

Kindly suggest how should I Modify my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`listStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) from the Hadoop FileSystem to list all the folders from the input folder and filter on the date part :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import java.time.{ZonedDateTime, ZoneId}
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val inputPath = "hadoop/user/src/2021-01-22"

val startDate = inputPath.substring(inputPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
val endDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")).minusDays(1))

val baseFolder = new Path(inputPath.substring(0, inputPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))

val files = baseFolder.getFileSystem(sc.hadoopConfiguration).listStatus(baseFolder).map(_.getPath.toString)
val filtredFiles = files.filter(path => path.split("/").last > startDate &&  path.split("/").last < endDate)

// finally load only the folders you want
val df = spark.read.csv(filtredFiles: _*)
```

You could also pass a [`PathFilter`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/PathFilter.html) function to `listStatus` to filter the paths while scanning the base folder